# Limit Upload bandwidth for S3 sync with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

AWS provides a config to limit the upload bandwidth when copying files to s3 from ec2 instances. This can be configured by below AWS config.

```
aws configure set default.s3.max_bandwidth
```

Once we set this config and run an AWS CLI command to cp files to s3 bandwidth is limited.

But when I run the s3_sync ansible module on the same ec2 instance that limitation is not getting applied. Any possible workaround to apply the limitation to ansible as well?

Comment: can't find any argument in ansible to set this limit. May be you can use `command:` and set this. you will need the aws cli already installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible because botocore may not support this.
Mostly is up to Amazon to fix their python API.

For example Docker module works fine by sharing confugration between cli and python-api.

Obviously that I assumed you did run this command locally as the same user because otherwise the aws config you made would clearly not be used.

Comment: If you do not pass any credentials to the module if should use same as your user, including settings. If it does not work it worth raising a bug, almost for sure to boto. Stuff like this are not usually implemented at high level (ansible module).